# Python beginner: outputting function-generated text to file

Tags: python, python-2.7

Python newbie here, running 2.7.

I am trying to create a program that uses a function to generate text, and then outputs the function-generated text to a file.

I have no problem printing the function in Python

I have no problem outputting manually-entered text: (like this) http://codepad.org/JrcUTZfC

But when I try to output function-generated text, it isn't working: http://codepad.org/Wyj5Li8Y

I typically get a "character buffer" error.

Please let me know what I need to do differently.

Answer (score 4):

You probably want to return strings from your function rather than printing them. Something like this:

```
def fn(a,b,c):
    return "Template string {0} {1} {2}".format(a,b,c)
```

As for the iteration/concatenation part, this should do what you need. Note that the newline character ('\n') needs to be explicitly added, which wouldn't be the case if you were using print.

```
def iter_cat(a,b):
    x = ""
    while a < b:
        x += 'This is string {0}, {1}\n'.format(a,b) # x gets previous x with "This.." appended
        a += 1
    return x
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with the function itself, not with writing the output to the file.  You've written your function without using "return". That's legal in python, but it means that the function will return None by default.

Instead of saying

```
print "votes%d_%d.append(v%d_%d_%d)" % (b,c,a,b,c,)
```

use

```
data_to_write = "votes%d_%d.append(v%d_%d_%d)" % (b,c,a,b,c,)
data_to_write_two = # etc.
return data_to_write, data_to_write_two #etc. as needed
```

Then you can call your function just as previously

```
x, x2 = myfunc()
out_file = open("code.txt", "w")
out_file.write(x)
#etc.
```

You were using .write correctly - but all you were writing was None.  Remember, "print" only talks to the terminal, not to files or variables.

Comment: Thanks (this extends to @Nathan as well), but this introduces a new problem. When I use print (like this: http://codepad.org/KftHaO6x), it iterates, as I want it to. When I use your method (like this: http://codepad.org/8GJpp9QY) it does not iterate. Only one line of text is written into the file, as opposed to the many lines of text which appear when using Print.

Comment: OK, you have a subtle error here: a function stops executing the first time it hits a return statement, so your function is only returning data_to_write.  Do "return data_to_write, data_to_write_two, data_to_write_three" all on the same line, don't split the return statements.

Comment: You'll also have to loop through your lines explicitly when you write them to the file.  Try `x = myfunc()` then `for line in x: out_file.write('%s\n' %line)`  Apologies about the lack of line breaks here in the comments.  You're also using 'a' instead of 'w' in open, which will not work.